# Creating high sized road masks

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I am currently working the QGIS software and I want to extract roads of a certain region from OSM (Open Street Maps) in order to create a black and white .tiff mask as follows:
[image: The roads that should be exported to .tiff]

It is also preferable that the mask keeps the geoData encapsulated.

I do have 2 layers, the vector roads and the black background that is behind them.
My problem is with exporting, as the background is big (33806 * 21462 px) I was not able to export the above picture **with this exact desired size** (which is crucial for my project).

I do however have the vector roads in a .dxf file and a black background as .tif with the desired height and width, each one by itself.

I am looking for a way to merge them into one file without losing the original size.
I tried using ArcGIS but I am not familiar with it.

Comment: Please explain, how you're going about the export and why it doesn't work out for you.

Comment: If we are talking about QGIS, I planned to export using the "Export to image" submenu, and then selecting the black map as a delimiter for coordinates, and putting the scale to 1:1. When I do this the size of the image to export becomes > 99999 px * 99999 ( while my raster layer is exactly  (33806 * 21462 px) as stated. Even if I input this exact size in the submenu, qgis still fails to export it. This is why I am looking to alternative solutions.

Comment: A scale of 1:1 means that 1 m in the image corresponds to 1 m in reality. So if you have a pixel size of 10x10 m, one pixel of the image is exported as 10 x 10 pixel.